# How to use dynamic HTML tags in golang template?

Tags: go, templates

I am trying to render a headline with a dynamic tag (fallback should be `h2`).

```
<{{ or .Settings.headlineTag "h2" }}> 
  {{ .Content.headline }}
</ {{ or .Settings.headlineTag "h2" }}>
```

Unfortunately the output is escaped:

```
&lt;h2>
  Headline
&lt;/ h2>
```

How can I make this work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#hdr-Typed_Strings:

> By default, this package assumes that all pipelines produce a plain text string. It adds escaping pipeline stages necessary to correctly and safely embed that plain text string in the appropriate context.
>
> When a data value is not plain text, you can make sure it is not over-escaped by marking it with its type.
>
> Types HTML, JS, URL, and others from content.go can carry safe content that is exempted from escaping.

Here is an example that creates a function to compose the tag and return a `template.HTML`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    data := []struct {
        Tag     string
        Content string
    }{
        {
            Tag:     "h1",
            Content: "How to use dynamic <HTML> tags in golang template?",
        },
        {
            Content: `.Settings.headlineTag "h2"`,
        },
    }

    const tpl = `
{{ range . }}
  {{ tag .Tag "h2" .Content }}
{{ end }}
`

    t, err := template.New("webpage").
        Funcs(template.FuncMap{
            "tag": func(tag, fallback, content string) template.HTML {
                name := tag
                if name == "" {
                    name = fallback
                }

                v := fmt.Sprintf("<%s>%s</%s>", name, template.HTMLEscapeString(content), name)
                return template.HTML(v)
            },
        }).
        Parse(tpl)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Output:

```html
<h1>How to use dynamic &lt;HTML&gt; tags in golang template?</h1>

<h2>.Settings.headlineTag &#34;h2&#34;</h2>
```

Comment: [template.HTML encapsulates a known safe HTML document fragment. It should not be used for HTML from a third-party, or HTML with unclosed tags or comments](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#HTML). I have updated the answer that creates a function to do the job.